# Are questions of tool (and tool company) history off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I know I  was having a little fun with the [saw nib question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/539/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-saw-nib), but now I'm wondering about serious questions that have more to do with tool history and lore. For example:

- Why are combination planes (like the Stanley #55) no longer manufactured?
- Is the Buck Bros. of today the same company as the one from the 1800s?
- Were Scioto planes really made with prison labor?
- Why aren't pin and cove dovetails used today?

Are these still considered on topic?

As a hand tool enthusiast, I find knowing the story of tools to be fascinating. Knowing how things were done before power tools has filled hours of my time in musty old shops talking to musty old men about tricks and techniques that are slowly being forgotten. I helps me to better understand the craft and the nature of wood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it may be a bit of a catch-22. If it's likely that there is a single correct, definitive answer to a given question, it should be allowed. But if the answers are more likely to be debatable or pure speculation, it isn't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format.